# publish/subscribe messaging with redis and ruby

Tags: ruby, redis

I looked over this documentation:

http://redis.io/topics/pubsub

It states:

When you subscribe to a channel, you will get a message that is represented as a multi-bulk reply with three elements. The first element of a message is the kind of message (e.g. SUBSCRIBE or UNSUBSCRIBE). The second element of the message is the name of the given channel you are subscribing or unsubscribing to. The third element of the message is the number of channels you are currently subscribed to:

```
> SUBSCRIBE first second

*3        #three elements in this message: “subscribe”, “first”, and 1
$9        #number of bytes in the element 
subscribe #kind of message
$5        #number of bytes in the element 
first     #name of channel
:1        #number of channels we are subscribed to
```

That's cool you can see the number of channels you are subscribed to as part of a bulk reply from subscribing to a channel. Now I try to get this reply back when using ruby:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'redis'
require 'json'

redis = Redis.new(:timeout => 0)

redis.subscribe('chatroom') do |on|
  on.message do |channel, msg, total_channels|
    data = JSON.parse(msg)
    puts "##{channel} - [#{data['user']}]: #{data['msg']} - channels subscribed to: #{total_channels}"
  end
end
```

However, I do not get that kind of reply at all. What it gives me is the name of channel, the data published to that channel, and then total_channels is nil, because there is no third parameter sent back.

So where is this "multi-bulk reply" that redis speaks of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the protocol is to send a subscribe reply message as the first message just after a subscribe operation. You do not get the number of subscribed channels in all messages you receive (just as a reply to subscribe/unsubscribe).

With the current version of redis-rb, you need a separate handler to process subscribe/unsubscribe reply messages:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'redis'
require 'json'

redis = Redis.new(:timeout => 0)

redis.subscribe('chatroom') do |on|
   on.subscribe do |channel, subscriptions|
      puts "Subscribed to ##{channel} (#{subscriptions} subscriptions)"
   end
   on.message do |channel, msg|
      data = JSON.parse(msg)
      puts "##{channel} - [#{data['user']}]: #{data['msg']}"
   end
end
```

Please note that in your example, the number of subscriptions will be always 1.